# Selecting dropdown item in selenium

Tags: selenium

Currently, I have this code.

```
  Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("pgList")));
  dropdown.selectByVisibleText("TestCustomerGroup070615");
  driver.findElement(By.id("select1")).click();
```

I've also imported import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select; , but it doesn't seem to do what it says it should.

Also I think it should be included that I invoke this while opening a new window:

```
  String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

  driver.findElement(By.id("addGlobal")).click();

  for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
      driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
  }

  Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("pgList")));
  dropdown.selectByVisibleText("TestCustomerGroup070615");
  driver.findElement(By.id("select1")).click();

  driver.close();

  driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```

What seems to be the problem?

This error pops up:

```
Exception in thread "main"         org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "div"
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: It opens the new window, but does not do anything at all.

Comment: Are you performing action on new window or main window. first close the main window and then switch to new window. Then continue with your action on new window.

Comment: Yes I am. I tried other actions in the new window and they work. This one just doesn't. And the ids are correct.

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.id("pgList")));` seems to a Div element and not a Select element. Can you confirm this or copy the HTML snippet?

Comment: *Element should have been "select" but was "div"* .It is clear the selector you've used return `div` not `select`

Answer (score 0):

Try to define WebElement using XPath and click on it:

```
By option = By.xpath(//select[@class = 'expression']/option[@value = 'value']);
driver.findElement(option).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("pgList")));
```

and after one of those methods to select some option needed:

```
dropDown.SelectByText("some item text");

dropDown.SelectByIndex(2);

dropDown.SelectByValue("SomeValue");
```